# i want save information in iphone

Tags: sqlite, core-data, save, plist

i want to save one table information without relationship in my app 
how can i do it ?

- save plist
- core data
- sqlite

if i can save on mutable Array with save plist system please help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> i want to save one table information
>   without relationship in my app how can
>   i do it ?

You probably want to read [iOS Data Management](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html) and [Getting started with Data Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_DataManagement_iPhone/)

> if i can
>   save on mutable Array with save plist
>   system please help ? Thanks

[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a)